# Deimos and Phobos minerals

Tags: mining, mapping, phobos, helium-3, deimos

I am searching for Deimos and Phobos mineral maps, which probably are the best candidates to find large amounts of He-3 or other valuable resources to send to Mars colonies in the future. I searched the USRA library and a few other sites but i can't find any info about this. Does anyone have relevant resources or any websites that can help me?